# Finding next available professionals efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a scheduling system to track the schedules and availability of professionals.  Users should be able to enter some criteria and see a list of the best matching professionals sorted on the professionals' next available appointment times.  The query for returning these professionals works but, as the number of managed professionals grows, the time required to return the results gets ridiculous.

The system works off of 3 tables:  **professional** defines the professionals, **availability** defines blocks of availability for the associated professional, and **appointment** defines appointments scheduled for the associated professional.  So, some sample data might look like:

```
INSERT INTO professional (id, name)
VALUES
  (1, 'Bob'),
  (2, 'Frank'),
  (3, 'Joe');

INSERT INTO availability (id, professional_id, start_date_time, end_date_time)
VALUES
  (1, 1, '03/06/2017 09:00:00', '03/06/2017 12:30:00'),
  (2, 1, '03/06/2017 13:30:00', '03/06/2017 18:00:00'),
  (3, 2, '03/06/2017 10:00:00', '03/06/2017 14:00:00'),
  (4, 3, '03/07/2017 08:30:00', '03/07/2017 16:30:00');

INSERT INTO appointment (id, professional_id, start_date_time, end_date_time)
VALUES
  (1, 1, '03/06/2017 09:00:00', '03/06/2017 09:30:00'),
  (2, 1, '03/06/2017 10:00:00', '03/06/2017 10:30:00'),
  (3, 2, '03/06/2017 10:00:00', '03/06/2017 10:30:00'),
  (4, 2, '03/06/2017 10:30:00', '03/06/2017 11:00:00'),
  (5, 2, '03/06/2017 11:00:00', '03/06/2017 11:30:00');
```

The query should return a resultset along the lines of:

```
name  | next_availability
----- | -----------------
Bob   | 03/06/2017 09:30:00
Frank | 03/06/2017 11:30:00
Joe   | 03/07/2017 08:30:00
```

I'm using the method found on [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1251.sql-server-how-to-find-the-first-available-timeslot-for-scheduling.aspx) (with some modifications to work with my actual setup) to find the next availability but, like I said, as the number of professionals, and their availabilities and appointments, grow in number, the amount of time it takes to return results becomes unreasonable.

And, one other requirement, just to make this even more difficult, the results should not include any professionals that do not have any upcoming availability.

The bottleneck, as I see it, is that the next availability has to be calculated for all of these professionals on the fly.  I've considered building out a table of available appointments but the upkeep of that table would be prohibitive.  Any ideas as to how to make this work efficiently?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

**EDITED TO INCLUDE THE WORKING QUERY:**

```
DECLARE @buffer tinyint;
DECLARE @duration tinyint;

SET @buffer = 15;
SET @duration = 30;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT timeSlots.*, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY start_date_time ASC )
    FROM (
            -- Create an "appointment" to define the start of the block of availability.
            -- If the start of the availability is still in the future, use the actual start_date_time
            -- as both the start and end_date_time of the "appointment". If not, calculate the first
            -- possible availability within this block based on the current time, a number of @buffer
            -- minutes (to allow the user time to complete booking, etc., and increments based on the
            -- duration of appointments (e.g., if current time + @buffer is 11:32, but appointments are
            -- 15 minutes each on the hour, round up to 11:45).
            -- Only look up to 2 weeks out.
            SELECT
                availability.id,
                'Start' AS type,
                availability.professional_id,
                availability.start_date_time,
                Iif(availability.start_date_time > DateAdd(Minute, @buffer, GetDate()), availability.start_date_time, DateAdd(Minute, (@duration - (DateDiff(Minute, availability.start_date_time, DateAdd(Minute, DateDiff(Minute, 0, DateAdd(Second, 30, DateAdd(Minute, @buffer, GetDate()))), 0)) % @duration)), DateAdd(Minute, DateDiff(Minute, 0, DateAdd(Second, 30, DateAdd(Minute, @buffer, GetDate()))), 0))) AS end_date_time
            FROM
                availability
            WHERE
                availability.end_date_time > GetDate()
                AND availability.end_date_time <= DateAdd(Week, 2, GetDate())

        UNION

            -- Create an "appointment" to define the end of the block of availability.
            -- Only look up to 2 weeks out.
            SELECT
                availability.id,
                'End' AS type,
                availability.professional_id,
                availability.end_date_time as start_date_time,
                availability.end_date_time AS end_date_time
            FROM
                availability
            WHERE
                availability.end_date_time > GetDate()
                AND availability.end_date_time <= DateAdd(Week, 2, GetDate())

        UNION

            -- Get alreasy scheduled appointments up to 2 weeks out.
            SELECT
                appointment.id,
                'Appointment' AS type,
                appointment.professional_id,
                appointment.start_date_time,
                appointment.end_date_time
            FROM
                appointment
            WHERE
                start_date_time >= GetDate()
                AND start_date_time <= DateAdd(Week, 2, GetDate())
    ) AS timeSlots
)
SELECT
    TOP 5
    a.professional_id,
    min( a.end_date_time ) AS next_availability
FROM
    CTE a
    INNER JOIN CTE b
        ON a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber - 1
        AND a.professional_id = b.professional_id
WHERE
    dateDiff( Minute, a.end_date_time, b.start_date_time) >= @duration
    -- Restrict results to those where the start of the gap is at least @buffer away from current time
    AND a.end_date_time >= DateAdd(Minute, @buffer, GetDate())
    AND a.type <> 'End'
GROUP BY
    a.professional_id
ORDER BY
    next_availability ASC
```

**EDITED TO EXPLAIN WHAT THE WORKING QUERY DOES:**

The CTE in the above query generates a table that essentially includes 1 row per booked appointment.  The plan is to find gaps of sufficient duration between those appointments.  In order to create boundaries for these appointments, a "Start" appointment and an "End" appointment are also included based on the start and end dates/times for the blocks of availability within which the appointments occur.  To make sure a gap of time that has already passed is not included, the start_date_time of the "Start" is either the start_date_time of the availability or the current date and time (adjusted to the next time slot's start_date_time) if the start_date_time of the availability has already passed.

As an example, given the sample data above, the CTE would return the following (showing professional's name instead of id):

```
id  | type        | name  | start_date_time     | end_date_time
--- | ----------- | ----- | ------------------- | -------------------
1   | Start       | Bob   | 03/06/2017 09:00:00 | 03/06/2017 09:00:00
1   | Appointment | Bob   | 03/06/2017 09:00:00 | 03/06/2017 09:30:00
1   | Appointment | Bob   | 03/06/2017 10:00:00 | 03/06/2017 10:30:00
1   | End         | Bob   | 03/06/2017 12:30:00 | 03/06/2017 12:30:00
2   | Start       | Bob   | 03/06/2017 13:30:00 | 03/06/2017 13:30:00
2   | End         | Bob   | 03/06/2017 18:00:00 | 03/06/2017 18:00:00
3   | Start       | Frank | 03/06/2017 10:00:00 | 03/06/2017 10:00:00
3   | Appointment | Frank | 03/06/2017 10:00:00 | 03/06/2017 10:30:00
4   | Appointment | Frank | 03/06/2017 10:30:00 | 03/06/2017 11:00:00
5   | Appointment | Frank | 03/06/2017 11:00:00 | 03/06/2017 11:30:00
3   | End         | Frank | 03/06/2017 14:00:00 | 03/06/2017 14:00:00
4   | Start       | Joe   | 03/07/2017 08:30:00 | 03/07/2017 08:30:00
4   | End         | Joe   | 03/07/2017 16:30:00 | 03/07/2017 16:30:00
```

Given the above CTE results, you can see that Bob starts work at 9:00 on 3/06 and has 2 appointments booked for that date, one from 9:00-9:30 and one from 10:00-10:30.  What the outer query is doing is taking the above table and joining it to itself, offset by one row, so that Bob's data from the above looks like (all dates are 3/06):

```
a.type | a.start  | a.end    | b.type | b.start  | b.end
------ | -------- | -------- | ------ | -------- | --------
Start  | 09:00:00 | 09:00:00 | Appt   | 09:00:00 | 09:30:00
Appt   | 09:00:00 | 09:30:00 | Appt   | 10:00:00 | 10:30:00
Appt   | 10:00:00 | 10:30:00 | End    | 12:30:00 | 12:30:00
End    | 12:30:00 | 12:30:00 | Start  | 13:30:00 | 13:30:00
```

The outer query then filters these results returning only those rows where the difference between a.end and b.start is at least duration minutes long.  The first row doesn't work because the difference between the first row's a.end (9:00) and the first row's b.start (9:00) is less than duration.  The second row **does** work because the difference between the second row's a.end (9:30) and the second row's b.start (10:00) is of sufficient duration.  In this way, the outer query returns only those time slots that are of sufficient duration and then returns only the first of these for each professional.

Comment: So a professional is available (during his general availability) if for a given appointment there is no other appointment starting at the end of the first?

Comment: What is the input? I need a 45-minute appointment on some day or I need an appointment from 9:00-9:45 on some day, for example. Edit: Also, it can become notoriously slow using datediff() with a lot of records.

Comment: Did you look at your execution plan and build some indexes?

Comment: It is going to be hard to optimize this for you without actually seeing the query.  We could optimize it if you showed us the query but it is hard to guess what you did.

Comment: @JimmyB, exactly.  The professional is available if there is sufficient time within a defined block of availability that is not yet taken up by another appointment.

Comment: @justiceorjustus, the input is just the amount of time needed for the appointment (e.g., 30 minutes).  For the purpose of this question, I'm just trying to get the first availability of each professional and return, say, the top 5 (e.g., the 5 professionals with the soonest availabilities).

Comment: @Hogan, yup and yup.  I'm by no means an expert when it comes to decoding the execution plan but I've spent a lot of time trying to figure them out and optimize the query.  Indexes are on all PK and FK fields as well as the start_date_time and end_date_time fields of the appointment table (although, to be fair, I didn't see much of any improvement by adding these last two).

Comment: ok -- when I look at this query I see a cte that creates a table with 3 rows per record -- one for start, one for end and one for availability -- then a query that takes that result and joins to itself to "merge" the first two filter against the 3rd.  This is much more complicated than it needs to be -- make two CTE queries -- one with start and end time (PER ROW) and one with with availability.  Then in the main query join these two.  One of the nice features of CTEs is that you can have more than one of them.  You could even use a good names (eg START_END_TIMES instead of CTE).

Comment: @Hogan, thanks for the reply but I'm not sure I see how that would work. The query uses a CTE to create a table with *2* records per availability block (a start record & an end record) and another record *for each* appointment that falls within that availability block. So, if the professional has one availability block with 5 existing appointments within it, the CTE will have 7 records for that professional. The outer query merges the start time of each row with the end time of the previous, filtering out those merged rows whose difference between the 2 times is not of sufficient duration.

Comment: @Hogan, Following up on my reply to your answer, I updated the question to better explain how my working query works and to show the kind of answer that I'm hoping to get from it.  Again, thanks for your help with this.  It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  I believe it is possible to generate the 2nd table in a single query but that might not be the best track to figure out your scaling problem.   Is every everything in your execution plan doing a seek?  Probably the only thing that isn't is the inner sub-query (since it is a sub query).  The standard remedy for that is to create a materialized view.  If that is the only scan in your execution plan.

Comment: FYI they are called index views in SQL Server - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx -- lots of good articles out there with a google search.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks for the lead.  It's a bit outside the scope of my previous experience but I'll check it out, hopefully learn something new, and hopefully find a solution to this beast.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here you go:

```
DECLARE @buffer tinyint;
DECLARE @duration tinyint;

SET @buffer = 15;
SET @duration = 30;

WITH TheDates AS
(
  SELECT 
    availability.id,
    availability.professional_id,
    availability.start_date_time,
    Iif(availability.start_date_time > DateAdd(Minute, @buffer, GetDate()), availability.start_date_time, DateAdd(Minute, (@duration - (DateDiff(Minute, availability.start_date_time, DateAdd(Minute, DateDiff(Minute, 0, DateAdd(Second, 30, DateAdd(Minute, @buffer, GetDate()))), 0)) % @duration)), DateAdd(Minute, DateDiff(Minute, 0, DateAdd(Second, 30, DateAdd(Minute, @buffer, GetDate()))), 0))) AS end_date_time,
    availability.end_date_time AS end_date_time_real
  FROM availability
  WHERE
    availability.end_date_time > GetDate()
    AND availability.end_date_time <= DateAdd(Week, 2, GetDate())
), dates_filtered AS
(
  SELECT 
    id,
    professional_id,
    start_date_time,
    end_date_time,
    end_date_time_real
  FROM TheDates
  WHERE dateDiff( Minute, end_date_time, start_date_time) >= @duration
    AND end_date_time >= DateAdd(Minute, @buffer, GetDate())
), existingApts AS
(
  -- Get alreasy scheduled appointments up to 2 weeks out.
  SELECT
    appointment.id,
    appointment.professional_id,
    appointment.start_date_time,
    appointment.end_date_time
  FROM appointment
  WHERE
    start_date_time >= GetDate()
    AND start_date_time <= DateAdd(Week, 2, GetDate())
), dates_without_apt AS
( -- filter out items with apt between start and end or starting or ending.
  SELECT 
    id,
    professional_id,
--    start_date_time,
--    end_date_time,
    end_date_time_real
  FROM dates_filtered D
  LEFT JOIN  existingApts A ON 
        -- apt between
        (D.start_date_time <= A.start_date_time AND D.end_date_time_real >= A.end_date_time) OR
        -- apt ends in range
        (A.end_date_time >= D.start_date_time AND A.end_date_time <= D.end_date_time_real) OR
        -- apt starts in range
        (A.start_date_time >= D.start_date_time AND A.start_date_time <= D.end_date_time_real) OR
  WHERE A.id is null
)
SELECT
    TOP 5
    a.professional_id,
    min( a.end_date_time_real ) AS next_availability
FROM dates_without_apt a
ORDER BY start_date_time ASC
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. As I see it, dates_without_apt is returning blocks of availability that do not have appts scheduled within them. But that's not what I'm after. I need to know the first available time that is at least duration minutes long, based on the gaps between availability_start and appt_start, appt_end and appt_start (of the next appt), and appt_end and availability_end. Looking at the sample data I posted, Bob's 1st availability is 3/06/2017 9:30 because, even though the block starts at 9:00, there is an appt from 9-9:30, making 9:30 the first availability.